# PostgreSQL dynamic table access

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I have a `products` schema and some tables there.
Each table in `products` schema has an `id`, and by this `id` I can get this table name, e.g.

```
products
    \ product1
    \ product2
    \ product3
```

I need to select info from dynamic access to appropriate product, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM 'products.'(SELECT id from categories WHERE id = 7);
```

Of course, this doesn't work...
How I can do something like that in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Those shouldn't be separate tables in the first place. Put them all in the same table, adding a column for the ID, and then select by that ID.

Comment: I agree with tdammers. It's a poor DB design

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I found a solution:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getProductById(cid int) RETURNS RECORD AS $$
    DECLARE
    result RECORD;

    BEGIN
        EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM ' || (SELECT ('products.' || (select category_name from category where category_id = cid) || '_view')::regclass) INTO result;

        RETURN result;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

and to select:

```
SELECT * FROM getProductById(7) AS b (category_id int, ... );
```

works for PostgreSQL 9.x

Comment: Hello, Alex I have tried this, but I got record in one column and got value in comma separated. I want in table format so would you please help me in this. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you can change your database layout to use [partitioning](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html) instead, that would probably be the way to go. Then you can just access the "master" table as if it were one table rather than multiple subtables.

You could create a view that combines the tables with an extra column corresponding to the table it's from. If all your queries specify a value for this extra column, the planner should be smart enough to skip scanning all the rest of the tables.

Or you could write a function in [PL/pgSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html), using the [EXECUTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) command to construct the appropriate query after fetching the table name. The function can even [return a set](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING) so it can be used in the FROM clause just as you would a table reference. Or you could just do the same query construction in your application logic.

Answer (score 0):

To me, it sounds like you've a major schema design problem: shouldn't you only have one products table with a category_id in it?

Might you be maintaining the website mentioned in this article?

http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Confessions-The-Shopping-Cart.aspx