# How to query a table whose name is stored in another table in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-schema, time-series

The situation is as follows:

I have dozens of thousands of sensors (lets say 100,000). Each sensor produces regularly or irregularly timed values in the form of `(timestamp, value)`. The step-width may be under 1 second, so in the course of a year there can be millions of `(timestamp, value)` pairs for a specific sensor, forming a time series per sensor. A user may request the values for a time period `(from, to)` for such a time series of sensor.

Storing all the values in one table (`sensor_id, timestamp, value)` will fill the table with literally billions of values/rows per month. This overwhelms traditional open-source database-systems (MySQL, PostgreSQL).

I am thinking of creating a table per sensor time series `(timestamp, value)` and reference that in my sensor table `(sensor_id, sensor_name, sensor_table_name)`. So there will be 100,000 tables with each some millions of rows.

Can I fetch the values directly using the `sensor_table_name` column in my sensor directly or do I have to do two queries, one to get the `sensor_table_name` and one to get the values out of that table?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772699/postgresql-dynamic-table-access). It should cover your situation.

Comment: Did you test this on PostgreSQL as it comes "out of the box", or did you tune the server; partition the table; use hardware appropriate to a very large database (VLDB), including fast disks and additional tablespaces; consider using SSDs for some indexes or smaller table; and so on?

Comment: Out of the box; can't change hardware, unfortunately. Do you think PostgreSQL can handle for example 60 billion table entries in a useful way?

Comment: The default configuration for PostgreSQL is geared toward people who want to download it and take it for a test spin on a minimal hardware configuration. Running a large database takes tuning. I haven't personally gone beyond a few hundred million rows in a table, but I would be surprised if it couldn't handle 60 billion on decent hardware with proper tuning. You haven't mentioned your hardware so I have no clue whether it is adequate. Putting OS and WAL on separate RAIDs with separate controllers will probably be crucial.

Answer (score 3):

If you use a convention for the Sensor Table Names, you wouldn't have to execute a query just to find out which table to query for a certain Sensor.

For instance, if your Sensor ID is Wolverine967, and your convention for names of these tables is Sensor_ + Sensor ID, then you'd know immediately that you could query the table Sensor_Wolverine967.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like a better solution for you than dynamically generating SQL statements with a name that matches the sensor would be to use [table partitioning](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-partitioning.html).  You could partition by sensor name, and that would work fine; but if you don't intend to keep billions of readings per year forever (without summarizing them), then you might want to partition by date range to make the eventual data purges a lot easier.

This will probably perform better than generating SQL statements on the fly, and should be easier to manage.

Comment: I have about 100.000 sensors (more to come, some to go, dynamically). The creation of that partitions seems to be much work and error prone. But I am not sure.

Comment: You are almost certainly going to be better off with all sensors in one (possibly partitioned by date) table than to have 100,000 or more tables for the data. Performance will not hold up with that many tables.

Comment: I'm guessing constraint exclusion won't scale to 100,000 partitions for partitioning by sensor ID and that's why you suggested partitioning by date?

Comment: Well, without a good reason to partition, it basically just moves the top level of the index tree to application code or constraint checking, which isn't any more effective that it is in a real index. It can help a little with vacuuming and such, but the benefit seems pretty minimal to me. If you can use the partitions for purging, by dropping entire partitions, then it does save a lot of work. And yeah, 100,000 tables kills performance, even if they are partitions.

Comment: Why will performance not hold up? In an B-Tree based file system like btrfs or ext4, opening one in 100,000 tables should at most take O(log 100,000).

Comment: PostgreSQL expects that you might have billions of rows in a table, so accessing table rows on that scale is very fast. On the other hand, the assumption is that you will probably not have more than a few thousand tables, but that table metadata will be accessed very frequently; so there is a cache for such metadata. That cache helps a lot for performance when the assumption holds, but it doesn't scale well to hundreds of thousands of tables. In PostgreSQL you are generally better of not partitioning unless there is a specific reason to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you will need to do two queries to do that if you use a normal relational database, one to get the sensor_table_name and one to get the values out of that table.